# Get-Command with parameters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to use the `Get-Service` command or `Get-Process` command
but I wanna try use a parameter with the "get" command.
I am getting and error with this:

```
$a = Service
$b = Running

Get-$a | where {$_.Status -eq $b}
```

this part is not working, either when I use this:

```
powershell -Command Get-$a
```

this one works, how can I complete with both of the parameters.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? Why is this needed?

Answer (score 1):

When you issue the command `Service`, and powershell is unable to find a command by that name, it'll automatically try to resolve the command name with `Get-` prepended - so `$a` already contains the results from executing `Get-Service`.

Now, if you want to execute a command based on its name stored in a variable, you can use the call operator (`&`):

```
$a = "Service" # notice that we're defining a string
$b = "Running" # otherwise powershell would think it should execute a command right away

& "Get-$a" |Where-Object { $_.State -eq $b }
```

[As Mike Shepard points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49262800/powershell-get-command-with-parameters/49262932?noredirect=1#comment85530354_49262932), you can also execute a command by getting the corresponding CommandInfo object from `Get-Command`:

```
$cmd = Get-Command "Get-$a"
& $cmd |Where-Object { $_.State -eq $b }
```

Comment: I would recommend using get-command as well:
`$cmd=get-command "get-$a"`
`& $cmd`